# If another window is manipulated and I return to Kivy, the button action is ignored once

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Kivy to create a GUI.

If I go back to the Kivy operation after I activate another window, the Kivy button operation is ignored once.

This is a video of the operation.

[image]

I tried the following code

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size

        TextInput:
            text: root.text

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Test"
            font_size: 48
            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import StringProperty 

class TextWidget(Widget):
    text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = ''

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.text += "test\n"

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'greeting'

    def build(self):
        return TextWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: its not a problem, it will select the window first. even most of windows applications like that

Comment: That is an operating system function called `click to focus`. On most OS's you can adjust your settings to change that behavior to something that causes focus to switch to a window when the mouse is moved over that window.

Comment: "click to focus" is something non-programmers can switch to on Windows and Mac ? Or does Python itself have such a feature?